# MongoDB indexing in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I have the following code as part of my application in which I have to enable indexing

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection(config.database.address, config.database.dbName);
var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      status                  : String,
      loc                     : {lon: Number,  lat: Number },
      createDate              : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
exports.registerEmployee = function   (objEmployee , callback)
{
 var employee = db.model(objEmployee.categoryName, testSchema );
// Saves data     
}
```

How to enable indexing for the above schema? Since the collection name (objEmployee.categoryName) is being created dynamically I'm kind of stuck here because for different category there will be a new collection get created. When we create new collection we have to enable Indexing also.

How to do this ?

Comment: What field(s) are in the index you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the collection name is dynamic doesn't affect how you'd create an index on `loc`.  You declare the index as part of the `loc` field definition of `testSchema` and Mongoose will take care of creating that index on each collection you register the schema for via `db.model`.  As for the index definition, you can specify that right in the schema:

```
      loc: {type: {lon: Number,  lat: Number}, index: '2d'},
```